# why it is possible to change a string passed to a function?

Tags: c

The code is:

```
void test(char buf[80]){
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    buf="changed";
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}


int main(){
    char buf[80]="test";
    test(buf);
        printf("%s.\n", buf);
        return 0;
```

The output is:

```
test
changed
test.
```

It is changed only within the test function scope, but it's possible, while it's impossible within the main function, there is the error:

```
assignment to expression with array type
```

I was sure that I need to use strcpy, but compiler doesn't throw any error. Thank you!

Comment: `char buf[80]` as an argument means `char *buf`. It isn't an array; it's a pointer.

Comment: "possible to change a string passed to a function" --> Hint: `test(buf);` does not pass an _string_ nor _array_. Array `buf` is converted to the type and address of the first array element.

`void test(char buf[80])` is receiving a pointer to the string. As such, the function can modify the string.  `buf="changed";` does not change `main()`'s string.  It simply re-assigns a local pointer.